# Why didn't my animation work as expected?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-popupwindow

I want to animate appearing of a `PopupWindow`. This is my show.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0.1"
        android:pivotX="90%"
        android:pivotY="10%"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"/>

    <scale
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="0.1"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="90%"
        android:pivotY="10%"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"/>

</set>
```

And styles.xml:

```
<style name="popup_anim">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/show</item>
</style>
```

finally:

```
mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.popup_anim);
```

As you can see, in my show.xml, I defined two animations and they should play in order by startOffset. They did well in this. However, **when the second animation start to play, it stops nearly at once** though its duration should be 600ms. So what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When are you triggering the animation, are you sure you're not stopping it inadvertently?

Comment: As the startOffset says, 200ms. Yes, I'm sure I don't stop it in java codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the second scale animation's  android:toYScale from 1 to 10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="0.1"
    android:pivotX="90%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"/>
<scale
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="0.1"
    android:toYScale="10"
    android:pivotX="90%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"/</set>
```